# How do I add captions to DT:datatable()?

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown, dt, quarto

I often use exchangeably `knitr::kable` and `DT::datatable` to show tables in my reports, depending on how many rows the data has. I need these tables to be numbers, so that they can be referenced to in the document

The problem is that the following code does not produce a table caption and reference for the first table and I have to use weird workarounds that do not work reliably or completely switch to manual numbering of tables.

````
---
title: "Example"
format: html
---


As you can see in @tbl-iris, this example does not work. However, it does
work for `knitr::kable`, as you can see in @tbl-iris2.


```{r}
#| label: tbl-iris
#| tbl-cap: Example DT table
DT::datatable(head(iris))
```

```{r}
#| label: tbl-iris2
#| tbl-cap: Example kable table
knitr::kable(head(iris))
```
````

This is the output of `quarto render test.qmd`:

[image: example output]

Comment: Lol, I just had a fun information with ChatGTP about this. It suggested three or four different solutions, all looking very believable, all incorrect ;-)

Comment: This is a known issue for interactive tables like DT or reactable with quarto. See this issue [#1084](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/issues/1084)

Comment: Yeah, I googled as much, but I was hoping for a viable workaround that is not too much hassle. I am currently cooking my own cross-references and this is quite a bother.

Comment: It should work now under v.1.4 prerelease of Quarto.

Comment: Yes, I confirm, it works with the current 1.4.550 release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for completeness: then answer is "install a new version of Quarto". Recent versions of Quarto handle captions to data tables correctly.